# Why can't I see point values anymore?

Tags: words-with-friends

I used to be able to play a word and see how many points I would get, so if I had a couple of plays available, I could choose the word that would give me the most points. now all of a sudden I do not see the points until I submit the word. Was there an update that changed that? is there a way I can change it back?

Comment: Where are you playing it? Facebook on a PC, iOS, or Android?

Comment: This sounds like one of the features they added that you have to pay for, perhaps they gave you a free trial period which has since expired, or they had a 'free weekend' or something as a promotional event. I can't be sure though

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the same on Android or iOS, but on Facebook, there's an option in the store called "The Count that lets you see point values of words. It costs 30 tokens, but I'm pretty sure that it always has, based off of [this October 2011 post where they announce it](https://www.facebook.com/WordsWithFriends/posts/10150449447958689). I think you get that many tokens for free though. Maybe you accidentally unchecked it?

[image: The Words With Friends store, with one item costing 30 tokens reading "The Count: You're here for words. We get it! See your score as you place letters."]